# Decode video raw data on Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, decoder

I would like to build a live streaming and viewer.
The streaming is H264/MEPG4 raw data.
How to decode these raw data on Android?
I can not find usable API in Android SDK to do it.
And suggestion is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Caxton

Answer (score 1):

I use ffmpeg to decode live streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) API (since 4.1).  Sample code here on [David Marques's blog](http://dpsm.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/android-mediacodec-decoded/).